# how to make container to be almost in half of screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have a question. Please see the image to understand better what I mean.
[image]

I want to create the yellow Containers like in the given image.

Here is my code:

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main(List<String> args) => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Mypage(),
    );
  }
}

class Mypage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mypage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Mypage> createState() => _MypageState();
}

class _MypageState extends State<Mypage> {
  TextEditingController height_controller = TextEditingController(text: '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        title: const Text(
          'BMI Calculator',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
        ),
      ),
   body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: height_controller,
                      keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                        label: Text(
                          'Height',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontSize: 30),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                ),
                const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                        label: Text('Weight',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontSize: 30)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                'Calculate',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 300,
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 30,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), color: Colors.amber),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap each children with `Flexible` and give `flex` value according to your design.

Comment: hi thank you  .. i tried to do what you told . but it wasn't successful.. maybe i am doing it wrong . can you help me more and give me more details? cause when i give it a flex nothing happens..

Answer (score 1):

SizedBox.expand > Column > [Expanded, Expanded] should give you a full-page with two equal vertical halves.  Like this:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox.expand(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Placeholder()),
          Expanded(child: Placeholder()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```